# Example of uncountable union of sets that is in $\sigma$-algebra but does not satisfy additivity property of probability

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$ be a probability space. I know that $\mathrm{P}$ should satisfy:
$$
\mathrm{P}(\cup_{n \geq 1}A_n) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathrm{P}(A_n)
$$
for disjoint family of sets $\{A_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subset \mathcal{F}$. I understand that countability of this family is crucial because $\cup_{i \in I}A_i$ where $I$ is an uncountable set may not be in $\mathcal{F}$.

I was wondering if anyone can give an example where $\cup_{i \in I}A_i$ **is** in $\mathcal{F}$ for some uncountable set $I$ but
$$
\mathrm{P}(\cup_{i \in I}A_i) \neq \sum_{i \in I} \mathrm{P}(A_i)
$$

Comment: What does the uncountable sum on the right mean?

Comment: Take each $A_i$ to be a singleton indexed by $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\cup A_i = \mathbb{R}$ whereas each set has measure zero.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: It means the limit of the net of partial sums defined for all finite subsets of $I$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : Isn't there any unique definition for uncountable sums?

Comment: Not a useful notion of sum! Then use Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. Then $P\{x\}=0$ for all $x$ but $(0,1)=\cup_{x\in(0,1)}\{x\}$.